# possible to add web.config file to my windows form project for wcf?

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF Publish Subscribe service in a windows form project. Is it possible to manually add a web.config file and make the service read the config and make it its config file?

As creating a WCF Service from a WCF Service project auto generates the config file, i'm not sure if manually adding a web.config file to my windows form project works for my wcf service.

thanks!

Comment: Please be more clear about the project structure. Windows forms project don't use web.config. See if the settings you need might not already be in app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be a `web.config` file, but probably an `app.config` if you're using Visual Studio. The proper config file name is `<application.exe>.config` (where application.exe is the name of the exe which starts your windows form, but if you have an app.config in VS it will rename it appropriately for you when you build the project).